Mat-table get column width
How can I get column header width (angular mat-table) in typescript? I tried to use id and get elementById.clientWidth but it doesn't work for mat table column.
I need to get the size of each column from the table to set the filter width above it for each column.
Example
TS:
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatPaginator, MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort, MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
  { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
  { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' },
  { position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C' },
  { position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N' },
  { position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O' },
  { position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F' },
  { position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne' },
];

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrl: 'table-basic-example.css',
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
  ],
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  ngModel: any = {};
  filteredColumn: string;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  getWidthForColumn(column: string): string {
    if (document.getElementById(column) != null) {
      let ss = document.getElementById(column)!.clientWidth;
      console.log(ss);
    }
    return 'background-color: white';
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event, value?: any, columnName?: any) {}
}

HTML:
<mat-form-field
  [style]="getWidthForColumn(column)"
  *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns; index as i"
  appearance="outline"
>
  <mat-label>{{column}}</mat-label>

  <input
    matInput
    [(ngModel)]="ngModel[column]"
    (keyup)="applyFilter($event, ngModel[column], column)"
    #input
  />
</mat-form-field>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.position}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th id="test" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Weight</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.weight}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.symbol}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>


please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a working stackblitz with the issue happening, ideally this should be done by CSS.

@NarenMurali Done

You can take the ViewChildren of all the headers (MatHeaderCell directive), then access the HTML element using (read: ElementRef). Which we then use to access the widths. I create an empty array, then load the widths in the ngAfterViewInit hook. Then I use ngStyle to add the widths using the index of the loop.
TS:
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  QueryList,
  ViewChild,
  ViewChildren,
} from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatPaginator, MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort, MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule, MatHeaderCell } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
  { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
  { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' },
  { position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C' },
  { position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N' },
  { position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O' },
  { position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F' },
  { position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne' },
];

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrl: 'table-basic-example.css',
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
  ],
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  ngModel: any = {};
  filteredColumn: string;
  widths = new Array(this.displayedColumns.length);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChildren(MatHeaderCell, { read: ElementRef })
  headers: QueryList<ElementRef<any>>;

  getWidthForColumn(column: string): string {
    // console.log(column);
    // let ss = document.getElementById('test');
    // console.log(ss);
    return 'background-color: white';
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(
      this.headers.map((header: ElementRef<any>, index: number) => {
        const width =
          header?.nativeElement?.getBoundingClientRect()?.width || 0;
        this.widths[index] = width;
      })
    );
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event, value?: any, columnName?: any) {}
}

HTML:
<mat-form-field
  [ngStyle]="{'width.px': widths[i]}"
  *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns; index as i"
  appearance="outline"
>
  <mat-label>{{column}}</mat-label>
  <input
    matInput
    [(ngModel)]="ngModel[column]"
    (keyup)="applyFilter($event, ngModel[column], column)"
    placeholder=""
    #input
  />
</mat-form-field>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.position}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th id="test" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Weight</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.weight}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.symbol}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>

Stackblitz Demo

thank you! I have progress with my solution, but there is an "Expression Changed After Checked" error, so I will use your solution :)
